# Unrecognized Selector NotificationCenter Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, selector, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I've read all of the possible solutions on stack overflow but not one works for me.

My code is

```
func foo() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fetchedUser(notification:)) , name: NSNotification.Name.init("dbReady"), object: nil)
    loggedUser.fetchUserByUID(id: current.uid)    
    return true
}

func fetchedUser(notification:NSNotification){
    let info = notification.object as! [String : AnyObject]
    print(info)
}
```

And in another class I've:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init("dbReady"), object: dictionary)
```

All of syntax for selector doesn't work

I tried:

```
1. fetchedUser
2. fetchedUser:
3. fetchedUser(notification:)
4. "fetchedUser:"
```

And other ten options maybe. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is it giving you compiler error?

Comment: [Did you read his one too?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40757389/5099208)

Comment: A self-contained example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351781/swift-2-0-to-swift-3-0-nsnotification-notification.

Comment: What is the full/exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was a selector with name didn't exist "fetchedUserWithNotification:".
I solved my problem by rewriting a new class and copy and paste all its content. Maybe it was a Xcode bug (IMHO the last version is plenty of it )

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3 the (system) notifications have this standard signature:

```
func notifFunction(_ notification: Notification)
```

So your function is supposed to be

```
func fetchedUser(_ notification: Notification){
```

And the corresponding selector is

```
#selector(fetchedUser(_:))
```

---

For convenience you could use an extension of `Notification.Name`

```
extension Notification.Name {
  static let databaseReady = NSNotification.Name("dbReady")
}
```

Then you can write

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fetchedUser(_:)) , name: .databaseReady, object: nil)
```

and

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .databaseReady, object: dictionary)
```

Comment: Are you sure about the mandatory underscore? Then why does this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39352319/1187415 work? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I'm not sure, but all system notifications have this signature (probably due to ObjC compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

It works on my project.

**Post Notification**

```
let dic: [String:AnyObject] = ["news_id": 1 as AnyObject,"language_id" : 2 as AnyObject]
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationKeyIndentifier"), object: dic)
```

**Notification Observer**

Add following code on required class where you want to observe.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.handlePushNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NotificationKeyIndentifier"), object: nil)
```

This is the function, which is trigger after observed by the notification observer.

```
func handlePushNotification(notification: NSNotification){

    if let dic = notification.object as? [String: AnyObject]{

        if let language_id = dic["language_id"] as? Int{

            if let news_id = dic["news_id"] as? Int{
                    print(language_id)
                    print(news_id)
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

Hope it may help you. If you have any problem regarding this please fill free to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.fetchedUser), name: notificationName, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Observer {

    init() {
        let name = NSNotification.Name("TestNotification")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationDidTrigger), name: name, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func notificationDidTrigger(notification: Notification) {
        print("Notification triggered ", notification.userInfo)
    }
}


let obj = Observer()

let name = NSNotification.Name("TestNotification")
var notification = Notification(name: name, object: nil)
notification.userInfo =  ["Name": "My notification"]
NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
```